# How do I wait for vacuum to complete?

Tags: ios, c, sqlite, vacuum

I'm building a cache backed by a sqlite3 database. To limit disk space used, I'm periodically checking the size of the db file. If it's over my max limit, I batch delete the oldest items and vacuum, repeating until the size is below 80% of the max.

However, the file size hasn't changed immediately after the vacuum, and I usually end up deleting the whole table before the size goes down. All calls return `SQLITE_OK` with no errors to be seen anywhere.

```c
while (too_many_rows) {
    // delete N rows
    sqlite3_exec(database, "VACUUM;", NULL, NULL, &error);
    sqlite3_close(database);
    // check file size
    printf("%d deleted, new size %d KB\n", N, size);
}
```

Produces something like:

```
200 deleted, new size 400 KB
200 deleted, new size 400 KB
200 deleted, new size 360 KB
200 deleted, new size 360 KB
156 deleted, new size 360 KB
0 deleted, new size 360 KB
0 deleted, new size 360 KB
0 deleted, new size 360 KB
0 deleted, new size 360 KB
0 deleted, new size 16 KB
```

How can I tell when the vacuum has finished, and I can check the file size again?

Can sqlite tell me or be made to block? Do I need to be using `inotify` or something?

Comment: If it's relevant, the platform is ObjC on iOS.

Comment: SQLite automatically reuses free pages. Why don't you continuously delete the oldest items?

Comment: Don't want to delete them if they don't need deleting. Don't want to be deleting frequently either. Both for performance reasons.